# When trying to connect remote clients to Cygwin/X, I get 'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified'

Tags: cygwin, xorg, cygwin-x

I just installed Cygwin/X and I launch it with `startxwin -- -listen tcp` to allow remote clients to connect to it through tcp.

However, remote clients fail to connect to the remote display with the following error message:

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the `xhost` Cygwin package, and after starting the X server, run the following (also on Cygwin):

```
$ DISPLAY=:0.0 xhost <remote_hostname_or_ip>
```

This command authorizes `<remote_hostname_or_ip>` (e.g. a WSL Ubuntu installation, a separate Linux system in the network, etc.) to connect to and use Cygwin/X.

Comment: is that supposed to be an export?

Comment: DISPLAY=:0.0 xhost xterm 192.168.122.5

No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"

Comment: @KenIngram remove 'xterm' from your command, you need to put the ip right after xhost just like in my answer.

Answer (score 22):

If you use VcXsrv, you should turn on *"Disable access control"* setting. But note, after that anyone from Network who has access to your X-server may show their UI on you X-server.

Comment: One note here: If you already launched VcXsrv, make sure to close it before starting against with the access list disabled :)

Answer (score 1):

I am running xinit 1.4.1-1 and xorg-server 1.20.4-1 with PuTTY 0.72. Like you, I added the startxwin parameters "`-- -listen tcp`". I just did it to the X-Win Server shortcut at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Cygwin-X`. I also needed to enable X11 forwarding and specify the path to .Xauthority file in PuTTY Configuration. PuTTY can modify the .Xauthority file directly without xhost.

[image: PuTTY X11]

Comment: In my case, I'm using VcXsrv downloaded from SourceForge, and enabling X11 forwarding for the PuTTY terminal was enough to get the X displays I needed.  Thanks for the help!