# Terminal in XRDP session. Solve 'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified'?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, xorg, xrdp, xhost

There was a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1174563/when-trying-to-connect-remote-clients-to-cygwin-x-i-get-authorization-required), but it was about Cygwin. My question is RDP. I set up XRDP on a Linux computer and used Windows' Remote Desktop Connection to connect to it. Inside of the RDP window, I opened the terminal, and typed `sudo nautilus` to run Files as root. But I got.

> Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
>
> (org.gnome.Nautilus:75012): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:40:24.020: cannot open
> display: :10.0

The accepted answer for the aforementioned question was typing `$ DISPLAY=:0.0 xhost <remote_hostname_or_ip>`, but when I tried `DISPLAY=:0.0 xhost localhost`, I got

> xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"

If I try `DISPLAY=:10.0 xhost localhost`, I get

> Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
>
> xhost:  unable to open display ":10.0"

Is there a way to solve this XRDP problem? This sudo password pop-up problem has been the single most pain-in-the-bottom, and no one seems to know the solution.

Comment: Same problem. Take a look at this answer. I just tried. It works. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417233

Comment: @canora I don't get it. My question was executing an GUI app in the terminal that is INSIDE of the XRDP session. That is, I connected to the Linux Gnome desktop using Window's Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209746/how-to-resolve-no-protocol-specified-for-su-user/417233#417233):

> xhost + local: